# Swap sections in ELF

Tags: linux, assembly, elf

Is there a way to force `gcc` or `ld` place code section at the end of output ELF-format file?

Maybe I can force them not to produce any other section except `.text` if, for example, I dont have anything in `.data, .rodata, .bss` and other sections?

Comment: You can do anything by writing a custom *linker script.* Read the manual for details.

Comment: As Fuz says with linker scripts. I'd be curious to know the spcial situation you have where you want to do this?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I want to add some code right after ELF's code section. It's just a specific app architecture that generates opcode but can't assemble it by itself so it needs a pre-compiled ELF, and then attaches to it. Thanks for the answer by the way!

Comment: @RandomGuy It might be a good idea instead to use the libbfd to generate an object file and then link it into the almost finished binary. Just appending stuff to an ELF file smells like trouble down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal version of script that worked for me looked like:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS 
{ 
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss :  { *(.bss)  *(COMMON) }  
    .text : { *(.text) }
}
```

But after I've made some more research ([docs here](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html)) I've replaced this script with default one (`ld --verbose`). Then I've just placed code section in the very end of verbose script and it worked perfectly.